# Loading mesh into RViz

Tags: ros, rviz, mesh, collada, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I would like to load into RVIz a 3D CAD model. The work was saved into .pnl format and afterwords converted to .3ds, .dwg, .dxf formats. The objective is to get .stl, .mesh and .dae formats in order to visualize the 3D environment in RViz. Using MeshLab I've loaded the .3ds format and convert it into .stl and .dae. Loading these latter files into MeshLab works correctly the environment can be fully observable but loading the files into RViz is showing just a few objects from the environments loading the Collada file and a white mesh loading the .stl file.
Could somebody give me a hint of another 3D free converter, or if I would upload the file to convert it to one the above mentioned formats.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11257/loading-mesh-into-rviz/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-09-20

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Blender for all of my file conversions. I've had trouble with .stl, so I've just been using .dae (Collada) files. Additionally, I use the OgreMeshExporter plugin for Blender to export to Ogre Meshes, and that works well also.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1